# Is it possible to control link heading between two turtles and how?

Tags: netlogo

I have two atoms (turtles) on a screen. On a candidate turtle(when mouse down) , there is a link 2 3 (between turtle 2 and turtle 3). 
I want that this **link will be headed towards the other turtle** called "atomOther". I tried facexy/set heading/towards, but none of them works.

Is it possible to control link heading and how?

Comment: This is very confusing. Your description says that the link is between turtle-2 and turtle-3, so the link obviously connects those two turtles. If it pointed in a different direction, it wouldn't connect those two turtles. Please describe the problem more clearly (or draw a picture).

Comment: I'll to be clearer: I created the link from turtle 2 to turtle 3. This link is an arrow. Now I want this arrow which is the link 2 3 to face turtle 1 (another turtle).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [`create-link-to` or `create-link-from`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#create-link-to) ?
the first makes a directed link to (pointed at) the target the other from it.
They are both called by turtles.
Remember, you can not mix directed and un-directed links in the same model (unless they are of different breeds). One work around for this is make one like from and the other thus

```
ask turtle 1 [create-link-to turtle 2]
ask turtle 1 [create-link-from turtle 2]
```

This creates 2 links between turtles 1 and 2. One to and one from turtle 1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification, the answer is no. You cannot make a link point in an arbitrary direction, because a link represents a relationship between two agents and therefore points from one of the two agents to the other in the relationship.

If you truly want a link to point from turtle 3 to turtle 1, even though the relationship is between turtle 3 and turtle 2, then use two different breeds of links. One breed is for the actual relationship and the other is for pointing. So, when whatever happens to make the arrow point in a different direction, you can use `hide-link` to make the link that points in the wrong direction invisible, and `create-link-to` for the arrow that points.